# Subtype polymorphism and arrays

Tags: java, arrays, polymorphism

```
Computer[] labComputers = new Computer[10];
```

with

```
public class Computer {
...
     void toString(){
     // print computer specs
     }
}
public class Notebook extends Computer{
...
     void toString(){
     // print computer specs + laptop color
     }
}
```

each subscripted variable `labComputers[i]` can reference either a `Computer` object or a `Notebook` object because `Notebook` is a subclass of `Computer`. For the method call `labComputers[i].toString()`, polymorphism ensures that the correct `toString` method is called.

I wonder what if we do

```
Notebook[] labComputers = new Notebook[10];
```

what kind or error would I get if I reference with `Computer` object and a `Notebook` object

Comment: Did you mean `Computer[] labComputers = new Notebook;` in the last line of code?

Comment: @ForceMagic ok, if `Computer[] labComputers = new Notebook[10];` is the case, what kind of error would i get?

Comment: Somewhat related and _great_ to read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/778118

Comment: Since the answer was longer than I could do in a comment I posted an Answer for it. I tried to explain you more about polymorphism, I hope I was clear enough :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since the question specifically asks about `kind of error` I will explain them with below scenarios

If you do below

```
Notebook[] labComputers = new Notebook[10];
```

Now you can only set Notebook objects in array.

```
labComputers[0]  = new Notebook(); // Fine
labComputers[1]  = new Computer(); // Compilation error
```

Now if you do

```
Computer[] notebooks = new Notebook[10];
notebooks[0] = new Notebook();
notebooks[1] = new Computer(); // <--- ArrayStoreException
```

Because arrays are `covarant`,`reified` in nature ie. if `Sub` is a subtype of `Super`, then the array type `Sub[]` is a subtype of `Super[]`, and arrays enforce their element types at run time it will cause ArrayStoreException

You can read oracle docs about [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) to know more how it works.

Comment: if I do `Computer[] labComputers = new Notebook[10]` what kind of error would i get?

Comment: There would be no errors. BaseClass Type can contain objects of child class.

Answer (score 9):

I think you have to understand how polymorphism works.

**Polymorphism is a feature that allow multiples data type to behave the same way through a common interface.**

For instance,

```
      Computer  // Base class
       |    |
 Notebook   Desktop    // Both inherits of Computer
```

Polymorphism would allow you to manage an array of Computer, no matter if they are a Notebook or a Desktop.

```
Computer[] computerArray = new Computer[2];

computerArray[0] = new Notebook();
computerArray[1] = new Desktop();
```

The advantage of this, is that you don't have to know which subtype of computer you are working with. They will behave as computer.

Now comes the big difference, in your Computer class you could have :

```
public Class Computer 
{
    abstract void MoveMouse();
}
```

This will give you the opportunity to redefine this method differently in Notebook and Desktop. MoveMouse() will now be available to computeArray because we defined it in Computer.

If you do this:

```
computerArray[0].MoveMouse(); // which contains a Notebook

computerArray[1].MoveMouse(); // which contains a Desktop
```

that will call the function that is implemented in `Notebook` or `Desktop`.

An example of those function implementation:

```
public Class Notebook extends Computer
{
    void MoveMouse();
    {
         MousePad.Move();
    }
}

public Class Desktop extends Computer
{
    void MoveMouse();
    {
         USBMouse.Move();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Each subscripted variable `labComputers[i]` can reference either a `Computer` object or a `Notebook` object.

This is technically true, but you must bear in mind that every `Notebook` is a `Computer` object, but **not** every `Computer` is a `Notebook`.

Therefore, if you had

```
Notebook[] labComputers = new Notebook[10];
```

you would *not* be able to place `Computer` instances in the array because not every `Computer` is a `Notebook` - and your array can hold only `Notebook`s.